# Karate - client certificate usage

Tags: api, karate

I have a set of api for new module where I am implementing Karate framework poc.

Where the api call uses client certificate with crt file,key file and passphrase.

Need to understand how do I need to use this combo in configure ssl

Comment: please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#x509-certificate-authentication